# How to crop the image created with <img> tag from top and bottom with percentage

Tags: jquery, image, crop

I have a slider with images created with `<img>` tag and now wanted to crop them easily from top and bottom with the percentage number. Is that possible in some way with css or js?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I have tried some code with background set to div but with didnt have a clue how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to actually crop the file (and save croped file) you should go for someething like Jqmagick (Imagemagick) http://jqmagick.imagemagick.org/

If you just want to show the upper part (or lower part) you can play with negative margins and so on.

Please give more details :)

Comment: I need soemthing with css so not actually crop the image, soemthing that will allow just crop the image from top and bottom with percentage number. is that possible @javirs?

Comment: For the top part i managed with negative margin but if i need both top and bottom what i could do? Any ideas @javirs ?

Comment: I have managed with negative margins! Thanks for the idea @javirs!!